# Autocomplete in Silverlight5

Tags: autocomplete, silverlight-5.0, selectedtext

I Have One Issue With Silverlight Autocompletebox 
For Client Requirement I Want To Use Autocompletebox with Selected Text Property Because client want Select From List Or Input Text Also....

And Also I Want To Set Selected Record From Grid But When I Select Record From Grid Some Time It Should Set Proper In Autocomplete But Some Time It Not Set

I Can Bind Selected Text Property of Autocomplete

What Should I Do ?

plz help me for this issue

Thanks

```
<sdk:AutoCompleteBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"  Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="18" Padding="0"
                                             ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ResEdit,Path=DataContext.AccNumbers,Mode=OneWay}"
                                             IsTextCompletionEnabled="True" TabIndex="7"
                                             SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=ResEdit,Path=DataContext.SelectedAccount,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                             Text="{Binding ElementName=ResEdit,Path=DataContext.SelectedAccountText,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                             LostFocus="AutoCompleteBox_LostFocus"
Visibility="{Binding ElementName=ResEdit,Path=DataContext.IsReadOnlyGlAccount,Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}">
        <sdk:AutoCompleteBox.TextBoxStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="{Binding ElementName=ResEdit,Path=DataContext.InitContrlos.ACCOUNT_NUMBER_OBJEnable,Converter={StaticResource ReadOnlyConverter}}"/>
            </Style>
        </sdk:AutoCompleteBox.TextBoxStyle>
    </sdk:AutoCompleteBox>
```

Comment: What have you done already?

Comment: My Problem Is Pending But I Manage With Both Property Of Autocompletebox SelectedItem And SelectedText Both

Comment: Could you show us a bit of your XAML, so we can suggest things?

Comment: This Is Edited Code If You Have Any Idea About It Then Thanks In Advance

Comment: Could we please ask that you clean up this question to both clarify specifically what you are asking and demonstrate what you've tried as well as to fix the English issues (e.g. Please don't capitalize every word; please work on making complete coherent sentences). You'll get more people willing to help you if you work on these things. Thank you.

Comment: You have too many things in your bindings, why have you got ElementName + DataContext.Something? You should have directly the Something binded.

Comment: I have parent lavel grid and that's datacontext is different and Autocompletebox datacontext is different so i can forcely bind with ElementName + Datacontext to bind autocompletebox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok ...

I don't know exactly what you want but ,

I found one related [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488968/silverlight-5-autocompletebox-bug?rq=1). for you.