# AutoCompleteBox.Text property is behaving weird

Tags: c#, .net, binding, autocompletebox

I'm stuck on a strange problem.
I have an AutoCompleteBox in my view

```
<sdk:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="txtSIA" 
 Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
 SelectedItem="{Binding SIA, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" 
 Text="{Binding TextSIA, Mode=TwoWay}"
 KeyUp="TxtSIA_KeyUp"
 Populating="SIANonSIU_Populating" 
 Style="{StaticResource AutoCompleteStyle}"  
/>
```

I implemented a field validator that check if its text isn't null or an empty string.
It works pretty well but the tricky part is that I have a button that Reset all my controls values, which code from my viewmodel is:

```
void BtnReset_OnClick(RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SIA = new SIA();
    TextSIA = string.Empty;
    BtnGeneralIsEnabled = false;
    DataGridSource = null;
}
```

Whenever I click it and then write in my AutoCompleteBox, the AutoCompleteBox is never empty or null even in my code behind in a key up event listener.

Here are some picture to illustrate my point:

[image: Text = ab]

[image: Text = a]

[image: Text supposed to be = ""]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488968/silverlight-5-autocompletebox-bug)

To fix that but we have to create a new autocompletebox and override the OnApplyTemplate method.

```
public class CustomAutoComplete : AutoCompleteBox
{
TextBox mytext;

public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
    mytext = GetTemplateChild("Text") as TextBox;
    mytext.TextChanged += new System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventHandler(mytext_TextChanged);
}

void mytext_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Text = mytext.Text;
    OnTextChanged(new RoutedEventArgs());
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Register to the TextChanged event of the AutoCompleteBox instead of the KeyUp:

"Occurs when the text in the text box portion of the AutoCompleteBox changes."

Comment: Try casting the TextBox via e.Source instead of sender. Does the TextSIA property implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Still doesn't fix it. 
The real deal is that it works fine except after clicking on the reset button..