# Silverlight 5 AutoCompleteBox bug

Tags: c#, silverlight, controls, silverlight-5.0

So I have this class:

```
public class AutoCompleteComboBox : AutoCompleteBox
{
   .............

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
           ........
           btnDropDowner.Click += btnDropDowner_Click;
           ........
    }

    private void btnDropDowner_Click(object sender,  RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
           this.IsDropDownOpen = true;
       // after this line, this.IsDropDownOpen IS STILL FALSE.
    }
}
```

When I click on btnDropDowner it should set this.IsDropDownOpen to true. 
I recently upgraded my project from silverlight 4 to silverlight 5 ( because VS2015 ) and I noticed this annoying bug.  In the 4 version the code worked perfect but now it just won't set that property to true...
 Is there a way to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Here's a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9480732/600559

Comment: This is not a complete answer, but the source code for the AutoCompleteBox is here: https://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Release/Silverlight4/Source/Controls.Input/AutoCompleteBox/AutoCompleteBox.cs . You might get some ideas about what it is doing behind the scenes from this code.